# Prevent VSC from opening a new terminal tab for each new coding session

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VSC for some Python coding projects, but I don't still understand why VSC opens a new terminal tab each time I'm running the same python script in a new coding session (monday, and wednesday and so on). Is it expected to work like this ?

I tried running my script in a "dedicated terminal" as shown here [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbRPF.png) , but doesn't change anything : if I close VSC, reopen it and launch my script, a new "dedicated terminal" tab will pop instead of using the previous one as shown here [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1ycl.png). At the end, I'm getting 10/15 different terminal tabs, quite annoying to track old outputs.

is there any way to centralize all your coding activities in a single terminal tab to keep all of your history/previous outputs in the same location ?

I have tried searching similar cases without any success, sorry if it already exists somewhere, and thanks for your answers !

Edit : I'm adding some screenshots to help figuring this out

Comment: if I have a terminal open when I close VSC, it restores the terminal when I reopen VSC for that workspace, containing the previous run output. I use launch configs to start debug or run sessions

Comment: how exactly are you running the script? what exactly is a "coding session"? what is a "dedicated terminal"?

Comment: 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) include the version number for your VS Code Python extension

Comment: I added some screenshots to help understanding. A "coding session" is just a time in a day where you're coding, so you open again vsc and get another terminal tab. 

@rioV8 Correct me if I'm wrong, but I will just need to create a custom workspace instead of the default one to keep using the same terminal ?

Comment: there is no default workspace

Comment: read the VSC Python pages and use launch configs, ignore that top right button, use `F5`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I just removed this line :

```
"console": "integratedTerminal"
```

from my launch.json file and worked like a charm, no more new terminal tab !